# Raspberry Pi and OpenVPN for web browsing away from home

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I am interested in setting up a Raspberry Pi to serve as a VPN router (with OpenVPN) to securely browse the internet while at school, work, traveling, etc, but I don't think I am understanding the whole VPN setup. If I have the pi sitting at home plugged into my router, will I be able to connect to it from locations outside my home and be able to access the Internet just like I were from home? Would I be able to check my bank account while at a hotel? Or is there a step I'm missing. I have read through a number of tutorials, but they all seem to have it setup so that you bring the raspberry pi with you and use the internet connection available locally and then connect to the pi which then routes all the traffic through the VPN. Is this correct? Any assistance/advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you want your Raspberry Pi to be sitting at home ready to be connected to it in case you want to securely surf the internet at some public wifi spot or so, then this is absolutely possible but requires some intermediate steps (instead of just plugging it into your router box).

You have to make sure, that your Raspberry is reachable from the outside world.

Let me explain some background. Every device that is *'behind'* your router (in the local area network *'LAN'*) is in a network that is private to your router only (usually having IP addresses in the range `192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.254`). These IPs are not routed in the public internet.

How then comes that I can use my laptop at home to surf the internet? Every device inside your home network talks to the internet via an IP that is assigned to your router only - but on the *'other side'* (the wide area network *'WAN'*). This means, that all your home device use the same public IP assigned by your internet provider.

This means in turn that watching from the WAN side every device in your home network looks exactly the same. They cannot be distinguished. Which it makes impossible to run an OpenVPN server on one of them -- i.e. your Pi. This whole process is called network address translation NAT.

However, there is the possibility to assign a public IP address to your Raspberry Pi via a so called [tunnel connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_tunnel). These services allow you to assign an public IP address to your Pi that is reachable from outside. But those services are commercial as IP addresses are rare these times...

But once your Pi is available using its unique IP address you are ready to set up an OpenVPN server on your Pi following for example [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04). There are numerous of such tutorials. And the setup of your tunnel broker connection depends on your tunnel broker (they should give tutorials for their systems on their web pages)

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comment section there is also the possibility to use the  port forwarding ability of your router to make your RPi visible to the outside world. Although it is a legit solution I would not consider it as the best for two reasons:

**1.)** The public IP address under which your router is available in this case changes periodically and gets reassigned by your internet service provider. This makes it *almost* impossible to associate your OpenVPN server with a fixed name like `my.rpi.com`, because the name <-> IP address mapping gets lost periodically. There are workarounds like DynDNS, but most of those services are commercial too.

**2.)** I don't know exactly how your internet service provider connects you to the internet, but in my case the WAN side of my router is located inside a network that is local to the company of my ISP -- this means that my actual home network is NATed twice: Address translation to the private network of my ISP which then gets translated to the public net. If this setup is also the case for you, then you have absolutely no chance to connect to your OpenVPN server from outside with port forwarding -- only a tunneled connection could be the solution here.

Comment: **However, there is the possibility to assign a public IP address to your Raspberry Pi via a so called tunnel connection.** Uh? Why can't you set up NAT to the RPi for the port used by the VPN?